# Grails - .withCriteria to get only records created within the last 5 minutes

Tags: date, grails, criteria

I am trying to get only the records that was created in the last 5 minutes. I found code that uses `between("date", now-1, now)`but that doesn't work in my case because the `1` there represents a day and that would mean I would have to write `now-0.00347` or `now-(5/1440)` coz that's what 5 minutes are. The problem with that is that the minus method can apparently not be applied to any datatype except integer. So if anyone knows any better way to get the records created in the last 5 minutes please let me know, I would really appreciate it. Here's what I got:

```
def activeUsers = User.withCriteria{
    def now = new Date()
    between("date", now-(5/1440), now    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use time categories to make date manipulation easier in Groovy. Such as this:

```
import groovy.time.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.TimeCategory

def now = new Date()
def beforeNow = now
use (TimeCategory) {
  beforeNow = now - 5.minutes
}
def activeUsers = User.withCriteria{
    def now = new Date()
    between("date", beforeNow, now)
}
```